# Linux command-line option to do video lens correction?

Tags: editing

Is there a Linux command-line option to do lens correction on videos?  (Either as a tool, or a collection of tools)

Specifically, GoPro videos?  I know I can do correction in GoPro Studio, but I need something that I can incorporate into a batch process.

Comment: On the Photo.SE site a [very similar question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/41260/9161) was asked and answered (by me). While not directly applicable to a video file, I think you should fairly easily be able to convert video to a series of images (with e.g. [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org)), apply the correction to the images and combine everything back to a video again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14772/correct-lens-distortion-with-ffmpeg which provides a possible answer.

Comment: See [Is there a way to remove GoPro fisheye using ffmpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40659507/1109017).

Answer (score 2):

Frei0r effects has a lenscorrection module:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#frei0r-1

this is an example to remove the fisheye distortion of a samyang 7.5mm

> -filter_complex 'frei0r=lenscorrection:0.5:0.5:0.16:0.6'

this is the docs from the mlt framework for frei0r lenscorrection
https://www.mltframework.org/bin/view/MLT/FilterFrei0r-lenscorrection

Answer (score 0):

Based on an an answer to [Correct lens distortion with ffmpeg](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14772/correct-lens-distortion-with-ffmpeg) it is possible with the [OpenCV toolkit](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html)

(That may also mean this is a duplicate question)